# Migrating from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

We are migrating the current SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 and we need a SQL server query to find the below objects and the syntax

1. Stored Procedures
2. Triggers
3. Functions
4. Tables
5. Indexes
6. Views

That will be incompatible with the current SQL Server 2016 so that we can modify them accordingly

Comment: I think while upgrading, the installer will automatically detect incompatible SQL Server objects for you and accordingly will suggest changes to make them compatible.

Comment: Currently the new server is in place we are moving by doing a backup and restore to the new server. There are some statements in Dynamic SQL that will be identified only at the run time. So can you suggest

Comment: I think [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017) is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You can look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-database-engine-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-2017

It is highly unlikely you are using any of the features that were removed in your actual objects (tables, views etc.) as they mostly relate to administration... You can always just set the database compatibility level back down (in fact depending on how you are upgrading/migrating it probably will be set appropriately anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to migrate the database from one server to another or lower database version to higher version then you should do with .bak file or with .sql script file of your database.